# Why tesseract is failing to give better output even though the text is very clear?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

For this image [link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8RvX.jpg) tesseract give expected output

**Expected Output**

```
Current Date/Time

03/18/20 5:03:49 AM

Name

LastwriteTime

Report-CorpAdmins2.ps1 01/18/18 3:10:15 AM

Domain Admins
Domain Name 1
Domain Name 2
Domain Name 3
Domain Name 4
Domain Name 5

Schema Admins
Schema Name 1
Schema Name 2

Enterprise Admins

Enterprise Schema Name 1
Enterprise Schema Name 2
```

But for this image [link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNeP6.jpg) it is not giving expected
output.

i am wondering what could be the reason and what i have to do to get proper output from both the images?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For example i just want to extract text from the image (cropped.JPEG).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pytessaract then there is no need for thresholding. just resizing and conversion to grayscale will be enough to get the desired output.

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
text_to_arr = (text.split('\n'))
space_to_empty = [x.strip() for x in text_to_arr]
space_clean_list = [x.lower() for x in space_to_empty if x]
print(space_clean_list)
```

EDIT:
I am using the grayscale image for this code. Right now I am reading the text horizontally. it gives me this results. you can do some preprocessing on your own.

> ['ps c:\users\vishnu\desktop> python .\sample.py', 'current
> date/time', '@3/18/28 5:63:49 am', 'name lastwritetime',
> 'report-corpadmins2.ps1 @1/18/18 3:16:15 am', 'domain admins', 'domain
> name 1', 'domain name 2', 'domain name 3', 'domain name 4', 'domain
> name 5', 'schema admins', 'schema name 1', 'schema name 2',
> 'enterprise admins', 'enterprise schema name 1', 'enterprise schema
> name 2']

Comment: This is the output i am getting with this code-----------------------------------------------------------. ['ps c:\\users\\vishnu\\desktop> python .\\sample.py',
 'tcl cae',
 'epl ee',
 'te ess eee',
 'to lola era cee eee ee esm)',
 'ool esm nu paa',
 'domain name 1',
 'em cues',
 'domain name 3',
 'cues',
 'domain name 5',
 'se eer',
 'aa le cua',
 'so cle cues']

Comment: can you share the grayscale image

Comment: i have added both the images